# Paytm Payment Gateway startTransaction response error

Tags: node.js, react-native, paytm

Paytm Payment Gateway React Native Mobile App.
After hitting this function => startTransaction response didn't go on then block but if any error it was going on catch block

```
const startRawTransaction = ()=> {
        const orderId = this.state.orderId;
        const mid = MID;
        const tranxToken = this.props.txtnToken;
        const amount = this.state.amount;
        const isStaging = this.state.isStaging;
        const callbackurl = 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID='+orderId;
        const appInvokeRestricted = true;
        AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
          orderId,
          mid,
          tranxToken,
          amount,
          callbackurl,
          isStaging,
          appInvokeRestricted,
        )
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("result", result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
```

[Response Error React Native Mobile App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFOYM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The function being used is correct, we will have to debug this at your end Please raise a query on "Paytm Developer Support". We would be needing more information to get this checked